# How to get the nth-order tesselation of a polyhedron in Mathematica?

Tags: polyhedra

I'd like to get the n-th order tesselation of a polyhedron like in the drawings on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron#/media/File:Geodesic_icosahedral_polyhedron_example.png
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron#/media/File:Geodesic_icosahedral_polyhedron_example2.png
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron#/media/File:Geodesic_icosahedral_polyhedron_example5.png

Mathematica Geodesate[] yields a subdivision / tesselation but I don't want the projection onto the sphere.
In the above pictures the second last is my goal.

My goal is to produce a generalized star polyhedron.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Cube"], 2]`?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't flat. I want all the triangles to be in the plane of the original facets.